# Pattern Matching (Any, Any) as (String, String) Fails in Switch Case

Tags: string, swift, switch-statement, swift2

Need help in following code.

```
let first: Any = "One"
let second: Any = "Two"
let values = (first, second)

switch values {
case let (x, y) as (String, String):
    print("Success", x, y)
default:
    print("Failure")
}

switch first {
case let x as String:
   print("Success", x)
default:
   print("Failure")
}
```

--- Output

```
Failure
Success One
```

--- Expected Output

```
Success One Two
Success One
```

Demo: http://swiftstub.com/65065637

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you are doing the casting wrong.

Here are the changes I have made to your code so that it works:

```
let first: Any = "One"
let second: Any = "Two"
let values = (first, second)

switch values {
case let (x as String, y as String):
    print("Success", x, y)
default:
    print("Failure")
}

switch first {
case let x as String:
    print("Success", x)
default:
    print("Failure")
}
```

**Output:**

```
Success One Two
Success One
```

Hope this helps!